# OSGi issue in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, module, osgi

I am new in osgi and modular programming.

I am working on an OSGi project in Netbeans. I have created a module suite with different modules, now I need to access a class object from a module in another using the import statements but its not working.Please how can i achieve this.

Comment: Why not give us your requirements then we write your application? :-) A more concrete example with some code, manifests, and exceptions would make it slightly easier to help you.

Comment: i have class person in module org.app.people, i want to use person object in module org.app.loan, i tried using 'import org.app.people.person' but its not working.

Comment: Now just imagine you're on the other side. You know a lot about something but someone has a question and the info you provide is all there is to go on ... You really must try to put effort in creating a tiny example that shows your problem and then ask others. This question is currently not answerable. Well, maybe the correction is to read OSGi in Action or so.